# How to set OnClick listener on Recycler View Adapters from within Acivity class? Or Access other RVAdapter from first Adapter?

Tags: java, android, android-studio, android-recyclerview

I have a layout where I use two RecyclerViews, each with its own Adapter.
On the Activity class of the layout I have the references of the RVs and I create them there. Then I dynamically create the buttons and insert them on one of the RecyclerViews.

The current problem I'm facing is that I'm setting the onClick listener inside the adapter itself but I want to hopefully set it through the activity class.
That's because the activity class has references to all the things I need to know when an object inside the recycler view is clicked and I want them to move between the RVs when clicked. From first RV to go to second and vice versa.

To create the view inside the first adapter I use.

```
for (Iterator<String> it = setList.iterator();it.hasNext();)
{
    String str = it.next();
    Object1 o = new Object1 (str, R.drawable.testicon);
    objectList.add(o);
}

firstRVAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
```

Inside my adapter I set the onclick listener inside the OnBindViewHolder as such:

```
@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(LeftViewHolder holder,final int position) {

    holder.imageView.setImageResource(verticalLeftList.get(position).getLogo());
    holder.textView.setText(verticalLeftList.get(position).getName());
    holder.imageView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            String productName = 
                verticalLeftList.get(position).getName().toString();
                Toast.makeText(context, productName + " is selected", 
                                       Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    });
}
```

Any recommendations or help how to change this to allow me to do what I want would be really appreciated. Either searching for a way to access the second adapter through the first one or a way to set the listener for each item inside RV from the activity class.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create a callback for your adapter to pass data back to your activity.

```
public interface AdapterCallback {
void itemClicked(int position);
}
```

see [Juan's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57377311/11881779) for example

Comment: Thank you! I will test it right now and mark it as solved if it works.

Answer (score 0):

Pass the `Activity` to the adapter in the constructor as a callback listener, and then, in the `onClick()` method call a callback on the activity.

(...) means there is more code not relevant to the answer.

In the RV Adapter class:

```
public MyAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<MyAdapter.ViewHolder>{
    Listener listener;

    public MyAdapter(Listener listener, ...){
        this.listener = listener;
        ...
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(LeftViewHolder holder,final int position) {

       holder.imageView.setImageResource(verticalLeftList.get(position).getLogo());
       holder.textView.setText(verticalLeftList.get(position).getName());
       holder.imageView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
           public void onClick(View v) {
               String productName = 
                   verticalLeftList.get(position).getName().toString();
                   Toast.makeText(context, productName + " is selected", 
                                       Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                   listener.onClick(productName);
           }
       });
    }

    ...

    public static interface Listener{
        public void onRVClick(String aParamToIdWhatWasClicked);
    }
}
```

And make the Activity implement the `Listener` interface and pass its instance to the RV Adapter constructor.

```
public class MyActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements MyAdapter.Listener {
    private MyAdapter myRvAdapter;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState){
      ...
      myRvAdapter = new MyAapter(this, ...);
      ...
    }

    ...
    @Override 
    public void onRVClick(String what){
        System.out.println(what + " was selected");
    }
    ...
}
```

Note that the parameter of the `onRVClick()` interface method can be whatever you want. It could even be the data list item backing the selected recycler view item.

Comment: Thank you for the code and answering. I already fixed it with Emir's answer but thanks a lot eitherway.